# FloatingActionButton in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-relativelayout, floating-action-button

I'm studying about the layout types in Android and I started construct a floating button and I would like to know what is the best mode to create a floating button in Android Studio. Using floatingActionButton library at Android Studio or creating without libraries.

Comment: That depends if the FloatingActionButton class that is provided by Android is sufficient for you or not. There are also other libraries for FloatingActionButton but most of them are deprecated because the class provided by Android is sufficient.

Comment: In my case I worry about leaving the application performance low by using libraries. I would like to know about the very high performance of the application or do the same thing as doing a floatButton with a native button.

Comment: Essentialy a FloatingActionButton is just an image view with elevation. I don't think you should be worried about it ruining performance. Go for the support library ones, they do just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use the support one when it answers your needs (or at least start with it until you see a major drawback).

Most of time, if the support library covers your needs, you'll be less likely to have bugs or issues with it than you would with a third party library.